# need meta tag usage browser timeout keep-alive

Tags: http, connection, meta-tags, keep-alive, page-refresh

I am trying to fix this problem but I have some doubt. How to use this tag?

```html
<meta http-equiv="Keep-Alive:timeout=600" content="600" />
```

or

```html
<meta http-equiv="connection:Keep-Alive" content="600" />
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? AFAIK there is no "keep alive" meta tag. Maybe you want `http-equiv="refresh"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *keep-alive* signal can't be sent with pure HTML; this is a server setting. Please take a look here: [How can I enable keep-alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232068/how-can-i-enable-keep-alive)

What you can do with HTML meta-tags is more about the browser cache. If you want to refresh the page every 600 seconds, the `http-equiv="refresh"` could get the job done (but here again, there are some more robust solutions server-side). It really depends on what you are actually trying to do; with some more details, we would surely be able to help you further.